# Sharepoint 2013 Edit webpart Tool Pane for visual webparts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to add custom values to the editwebpart tool pane for a visual webpart as shown in the image and once i clicked on it i want a popup to be shown.

Could some one please point me for some resources about this .

[image: Edit webpart tool pane]

Comment: I was able to get it done with the help of following links  http://nishantrana.me/2009/03/07/customizing-custom-web-part-menu-in-sharepoint/ added the code in visualwebpart.cs file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it done with the help of following links 
    http://nishantrana.me/2009/03/07/customizing-custom-web-part-menu-in-sharepoint/
    http://adicodes.com/web-part-verbs-in-sharepoint-2010/
    added the code in visualwebpart.cs file in custom visualwebpart

```html
     public override WebPartVerbCollection Verbs
        {
            get
            {
                // Client side verb
                WebPartVerb clientSideVerb = new WebPartVerb("clientID", "javascript:alert('Version 1.0');");
                clientSideVerb.Text = "About Client Side Verb";
                //// Server side verb
                //WebPartVerb serverSideVerb = new WebPartVerb("serverID", new WebPartEventHandler(ServerVerbEventHandler));
                //serverSideVerb.Text = "Server Side Verb";
                //// Verb for both client side and server side
                //WebPartVerb bothSideVerb = new WebPartVerb("bothID", new WebPartEventHandler(ServerVerbEventHandler), "javascript:alert(‘Hello World from Java Script Verb!’);");
                //bothSideVerb.Text = "Both Side Verb";          
                WebPartVerbCollection wbVerbCollection = new WebPartVerbCollection(base.Verbs, new WebPartVerb[] { clientSideVerb });
                return wbVerbCollection;
            }
        }
```